# How to make pylint stop complaining about a .so module?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module, pylint, .so

I compiled a python function in a module with Cython getting a my_module.so. It is in the same folder than other .py modules. I import it with `from my_module import my_func`. Everything works well but pylint won't stop complaining:

```
No name 'my_func' in module 'my_module' pylint(no-name-in-module)
```

I tried:

> $ pylint --extension-pkg-allow-list=my_module.so

And got the answer:

```
...
    --extension-pkg-allow-list=<pkg[,pkg]>
                        A comma-separated list of package or module names from
                        where C extensions may be loaded. Extensions are
                        loading into the active Python interpreter and may run
                        arbitrary code. [current: my_module.so]
...
```

But pylint is still complaining (I restarted vs code). Actually don't know if it was the right thing to do, and don't know what to do else.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I tried:
>
> $ pylint --extension-pkg-allow-list=my_module.so

1. You need to provide a positional argument to `pylint` to tell it what modules or packages to lint. https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html
2. The name of the extension package should be its "import name," i.e. without the `.so`.

For example:

```
$ pylint --extension-pkg-allow-list=my_module src/my_package
```